# Morris JS Line Chart Using JSON Array

Tags: javascript, php, json, morris.js

I was able to get some help on my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613174/querying-mysql-table-to-return-json) in order to get a concatenated JSON output from mysql. So now I have a JSON array that I'm trying to get to display in a Morris JS line chart that sits on a PHP page.

Currently this is what a `print_r($rows)` returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [json_data_records] => {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 21:15:56","sensor2":64.96,"sensor1":60.91} ) [1] => Array ( [json_data_records] => {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 21:25:58","sensor2":64.51,"sensor1":60.91} ) [2] => Array ( [json_data_records] => {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 21:36:00","sensor2":64.06,"sensor1":60.91} ) [3] => Array ( [json_data_records] => {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 21:46:02","sensor2":63.61,"sensor1":60.35} ) [4] => Array ( [json_data_records] => {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 21:56:05","sensor2":63.27,"sensor1":60.46} ) ) 1
```

But I believe the chart is looking for a structure more like:

```
[
    {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 00:20:00","sensor2":69.91,"sensor1":68.11},
    {"dateRecorded": "2018-04-02 00:30:08","sensor2":69.69,"sensor1":68.00}
]
```

I tried to set my data input in the chart config to `data: <?php echo $rows;?>` but I get an error:
`PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion`

If I copy each line of the mysql output and put it into the data setting of the chart config, everything prints out as I would like so I know I have the right structure and config set, just need some help getting it from the array to formatted. Would I use some sort of a for loop to iterate through the array and print out each line?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not very good to mix javascript and PHP code.. I strongly advice to load the array -encoded in a JSON- from the server with jQuery $.ajax. So that you would not such kind of conversion problem and you could reload the chart content whithout reloading the whole page.

Otherwise, yes you should do a loop with PHP and print out each line.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The data is stored in mysql and upon initial page load, the data is queried and stored in a php variable which is then passed to the morris chart.